# While using listbox.SelectedItem i am getting an error for getEnumerator, when i am using listbox.item i get all the items present in listbox .net

Tags: asp.net-core

This is the code I am getting error at:

```cs
var selecteditems=new List<string>();
foreach(var item in lstsubject.SelectedItem) 
    selecteditems.add(item.ToString())
```

Getting error as `foreach` statement:

> Cannot operate on variables of
> type'system.web.ui.webControls.ListItem'because it does not contain a
> public definition for 'GetEnumerator'

Comment: Please share you full code so that it can be reproducible easily that might help quick solution

Answer (score 1):

If you'd like to get all selected items of a ListBox control that supports multiple selections, and then add the text (or value) to a `List<string>`, you can refer to the following code sample.

```
var selecteditems = new List<string>();
            
foreach (ListItem item in lstsubject.GetSelectedItems())
{
    selecteditems.Add(item.Text.ToString());
}
```

*Implement an extension method `GetSelectedItems`*

```
public static class ListBoxExtension
{
    public static List<ListItem> GetSelectedItems(this ListBox lstbox)
    {
        return lstbox.Items.OfType<ListItem>().Where(i => i.Selected).ToList();
    }
}
```